# Lagging when translate (moving) between images

Tags: java, android, animation

I have a problem with translate/moving/change position between two image views for multiple images at the same time.  What I want to do is to make an animation shuffling of a deck of cards and when I shuffle the deck with face up cards, (52 different image views) application and animation moving is lagging BUT when i shuffle the deck with face down cards (52 same image views) there is no lag at the moving.

Below you can see the shuffle when cards are faced up:
[Shuffling lagging problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5KGr.gif)

What i want is to fix the shuffling of the deck when cards are face up in order not to lag anymore. How can i do this? Images of the cards are already very small size (6-8KB each one) and i tried everything with memory problems.